# emmeans:emmip_ggplot error "Error in emms$LCL : $ operator not defined for this S4 class"

Tags: r, ggplot2, emmeans

I'm trying the `emmip_ggplot` with this example

```
n.emms <- emmeans(neuralgia.glm, ~ Treatment)

emmip_ggplot(n.emms, style = "factor")
Error in emms$LCL : $ operator not defined for this S4 class
```

`emmip(neuralgia.glm, ~Treatment)` gives a traditional plot, without error or warning.

[image]

Thanks for stopping by.

Comment: As is documented, `emmip_ggplot` may only be called with a data frame having certain variable names -- essentially, only with a result of `emmip(..., plotit = FALSE)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`?emmip_ggplot` says the first argument to `emmip_ggplot` should be

> A ‘data.frame’ created by calling ‘emmip’ with ‘plotit =
> FALSE’. Certain variables and attributes are expected to
> exist in this data frame; see the section detailing the
> rendering functions.

Thus

```r
m1 <- glm(vs~hp+disp+drat, family = binomial, mtcars)
em1 <- emmeans(m1, ~ disp * hp, at = list(hp = 50:300))
em2 <- emmip(em1, disp ~ hp, plotit = FALSE)
emmip_ggplot(em2)
```

This works (i.e. produces a plot) but I'm not sure it makes sense, as I threw the example together in a hurry.